# Is there a know bug (using install4j - 7.0.5) for tabbing between buttons & hitting enter 'actions' the wrong button?

Tags: install4j

The issue is as follows:
Using Keyboard navigation only (no mouse) the user tabs to the 2nd Button
It is highlighted as expected and looks like it has the focus
User hits return
Expected: Actions performed as expected for 2nd button
Actual: Actions pertaining to the 1st button are actually performed

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 0):

The return key performs the action of the default button regardless of the focus. With the space key you can click the currently focused button.